# The code requires you to have an error pop up when if its greater than 1, less that 50?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I have to have the program display an error if the term the user types is less than 50 or greater than one so anything inbetween is an error. The user must type 50+ or 0 to not get an error. I was almost positive it worked until I looked at the project closer. I get the error when you type any number.

```
    Const strMSG As String = "The term must be less than 1 or greater than 50."
    Const strMSG2 As String = "The term must be less than 1 or greater than 50."

    txtOwed.Text = FormatCurrency(txtRegistrants.Text * 80)
    If txtOwed.Text > 50 Then
        txtOwed.Text = txtOwed.Text
    Else
        MessageBox.Show(strMSG, "Monthly Payment Calculator", _
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    End If

    If txtOwed.Text < 1 Then
        txtOwed.Text = txtOwed.Text
    Else
        MessageBox.Show(strMSG2, "Monthly Payment Calculator", _
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    End If
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to the following:

```
If val(txtOwed.Text) > 1 and val(txtOwed.Text) < 50 Then
  MessageBox.Show(strMSG, "Monthly Payment Calculator", _
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
End If
```

Note that I solved for your subject line, not your enclosed verbiage and example code

Comment: think about your if condition for a second, every number will be either greater than 1 **or** less than 50

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the easiest for most people to understand:

```
If not(txtOwed.Text > 50 or txtOwed.text = 0) Then
    MessageBox.Show(strMSG, "Monthly Payment Calculator", _
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
End If
```

but

```
not(txtOwed.Text > 50 or txtOwed.text = 0)
```

is equivalent to

```
(txtOwed.Text <= 50 and txtOwed.text <> 0)
```

Comment: It has been observed that the negation is a difficult action to comprehend - not wrong - just difficult

Comment: ok, but if they have trouble with negation, should they really be coding?

Comment: Coding, no. The issue is that negation can be a task switch regardless of your skill level - not always, but often enough to make me stop and weigh the options when it comes up.

Comment: Sorry I'm only 16 and a junior in a college course. New to C code. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: no trouble, @Cara.  Hopefully they'll send you to a boolean algebra class so you can get the education you need for this type of work.

Comment: Yes thankyou Beth. It sucks because my teacher actually teaches via web cam so I dont get much help.

Comment: oh, boy.  I suppose it's cheaper, but the quality of web-based instruction can't be as good as instructor-led.